# T - SQL advanced SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have this table :

```
   Date |    TV Show  |    Begin   |    End  |
===================================================
12/3/14 |GameofThrones|   11:00    |   11:55 |
12/3/14 | Breaking Bad|   12:00    |   12:45 |
12/3/14 |   Scrubs    |   12:46    |   13:15 |
12/3/14 |   Scrubs    |   13:16    |   13:59 |
12/3/14 | Breaking Bad|   14:00    |   15:00 |
12/2/14 | Breaking Bad |  15:00    |   16:00 |
12/3/14 |GameofThrones|   17:00    |   18:00 |
12/3/14 |GameofThrones|   18:00    |   19:00 |
12/3/14 |   Scrubs    |   19:00    |   20:00 |
```

okay... and my question is: how can I select only the first and the second entry of any given TV show?

Example:

```
12/3/14 | Breaking Bad|   12:00    |   12:45 |
12/3/14 | Breaking Bad|   14:00    |   15:00 |
```

I have no idea.

Comment: @Mihai ummm... right. That was a stupid question `-)

Comment: @Mureinik Well to be fair I didnt look until AFTER i saw that comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only one TV Show, use the `TOP` keyword to restrict the number of results. You could use the `ORDER BY` clause to sort the entries and `WHERE` clause to filter the resultset.

For all TV Shows, you can use a `Common Table Expression`.
Of course, you can use any `WHERE` conditions to filter the inner query's resultset.

```
WITH cte (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TV Show] ORDER BY [Date] ASC, [Begin] ASC) AS RowNum
    [Date], [TV Show], [Begin], [End]
  FROM
    TVShows
)
SELECT
  [Date], [TV Show], [Begin], [End]
FROM
  cte
WHERE
  RowNum < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM TVSHOWS
WHERE [TV SHOW] = 'Game of Thrones'
ORDER BY [DATE]
```

You might want to order or group by your query to filter to your needs, but the `TOP N` does excactly what you want.

Comment: You might want to add some columns after top http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/select_top.php

Comment: I blame it on LINQ. I get lazy and keep forgetting the most basic things